# Measurability of $\mathbb{R}^X$ in a compactification

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

Consider any (possibly infinite) set $X$. 
We fix on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^X$ the $\sigma$-algebra product of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$    (where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the extended real line with its usual topology).

Question : is $\mathbb{R}^X$ a measurable subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^X$?

Answer (score 2):

For each $Y\subset X$ let $\pi_Y: \overline{\mathbb{R}}^X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}^Y$ be the natural projection. 
I assume that $\sigma$-algebra product $\mathcal A$ of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra  on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is  a $\sigma$-algebra on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^X$ generated by the set $\pi_{\{x\}}^{-1}(B)$, where $x\in X$ and $B$ is a Borel subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. If $X$ is countable then $\mathbb R^X=\bigcap_{x\in X}  \pi_{\{x\}}^{-1}(\mathbb R)\in\mathcal A$.
Now we assume that the set $X$ is uncountable. The construction of a generated $\sigma$-algebra implies that for each $C\in\mathcal A$ there exists a countable subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $C=\pi^{-1}_Y\pi_Y(C)$. The set $\mathbb R^X$ does not have this property, so it does not belong to $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do you know that $C=\pi_Y^{-1}\pi_Y(C)$ for any element $C$ of $\mathcal{A}$ for a  countable $Y$?

Comment: @LCO By the construction of a generated $\sigma$-algebra. It can be easily proved by natural transfinite induction, but even more easy is a remark that the family of all such $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all the above generators of $\mathcal A$, so it contains $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Is it obvious that this family is a $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: Yes. It can be easily checked, that it has all properties of a $\sigma$-algebra. If $C=\pi^{-1}_{Y}\pi_{Y}(C)$ then $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^X\setminus C=\pi^{-1}_{Y}\pi_{Y}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}^X\setminus C)$.
If $C_n=\pi^{-1}_{Y_n}\pi_{Y_n}(C_n)$ for each $n$ then $\bigcup C_n=\pi^{-1}_{Y}\pi_{Y}(\bigcup C_n)$ and $\bigcap C_n=\pi^{-1}_{Y}\pi_{Y}(\bigcap C_n)$, for $Y=\bigcup Y_n$.

Comment: Since the direct image is not compatible with complementation (the complement of a direct image is not always equal to the direct image of the complement), I'm already stuck when I check the first claim. It's maybe obvious but I don't see it. Is there a reference for this result ?

Comment: Note that the considered sets are full preimages. Do you the equalities now?

Comment: Using that $C$ is a preimage, I only get to : $C^c = \pi_Y^{-1}((\pi_Y(C))^c)$ ($A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$)

Comment: For remaining equalities use that since $C_n=\pi_{Y_n}^{-1}(\pi_{Y_n}(C_n))$ and $Y_n\subset Y$ then also $C_n=\pi_{Y}^{-1}(\pi_{Y}(C_n))$.

Comment: I'm still stuck for the first equality. How to derive $\pi_Y(C)^c =\pi_Y(C^c)$ ?

Comment: A base of a vision of these equalities from me is that for each $a=(a_x)_{x\in X}\in\overline{\Bbb R}^X$ we have $a\in C$ iff $a_x\in\pi_{\{x\}}(C)$ for each $x\in Y$.